# SOAP with Java and C# - Clientside Object Handling

Tags: c#, java, soap

When I use SOAP, can I have complex datatypes as returnvalues or parameters

example:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getMyDataType")
public MyDataType getMyDataType(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) {  return new MyDatatype(bla)}
```

and if yes, how can the client work with the "unknown" types?

my server is in Java and the Client in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible, although I haven't tried it: You can try to generate WSDL from annotated  Java class and later from the WSDL file generate client C# code.

Comment: yeah, you're right, I didn't realize that the domain classes are generatet in a single file, thanks

Comment: @k-deux maybe you can add some annotations to returned classes to tell the WSDL generator to take them into consideration? or create some intermediary structures? if that wont help I have no further ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It should work both ways. What will happen is that the IDE (or you) will create a custom type in each language that can be serialized/deserialized into SOAP XML. I know VS will auto-generate classes from a WSDL; Java doesn't have one specific dev environment, but I would suspect some of the more popular ones like Eclipse might.

Like HTML, SOAP is an open standard specifically designed to allow differing implementations of the standard to work with each other. I have no doubt you can get this to work; I'm just a bit light on the Java specifics.